# Doxygen: How can I document macros that are not #defined?

Tags: c++, macros, doxygen, undefined-symbol

I am trying to use Doxygen to document the functions of some option-controlling macros symbols, for example:

```
 //! \def BOOST_SOMEFEATURE
 /*! \brief Option macro that is not normally defined
  *  but can optionally be defined by consumers to activate the option.
 */
```

But this will NOT be indexed and the comment will be ignored because the macro isn't defined.

A Doxygen macro symbol entry will only be produced in the documentation when there is a `#define` like

```
#define BOOST_SOMEFEATURE
```

in the header and other files.

Can I force documentation of the macro symbol other than by nasty fudges like

```
  #undef BOOST_SOMEFEATURE
```

or perhaps including a dummy .cpp file that contains `#define`s for all the macro symbols that control options?

```
  #define BOOST_SOMEFEATURE
  #define BOOST_SOMEOTHERFEATURE
  ...
```

Comment: At least when I understand your question well it should be possible to make a block around these definitions and documentation with e.g. #ifdef DOXYGEN_GENERATION and define DOXYGEN_GENERATION in your Doxyfile.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds plausible, but I don't yet understand how I can #define BOOST_SOMEFEATURE in the doxyfile so that it will be indexed by Doxygen.

Please can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 4):

Do the following:

1. Add the following line to your Doxyfile:

   ```
   PREDEFINED = _DOXYGEN_
   ```
2. Put your `#define` macros inside an `#ifdef _DOXYGEN_` section:

   ```
   #ifdef _DOXYGEN_
       /*!
        * Documentation describing the BOOST_SOMEFEATURE macro.
        */
       #define BOOST_SOMEFEATURE

       /*!
        * Documentation describing the BOOST_SOMEOTHERFEATURE macro.
        */
       #define BOOST_SOMEOTHERFEATURE
   #endif
   ```

With this method, your macros will not be seen by the preprocessor during a normal build, but will be seen by Doxygen.

You can put this section anywhere in your code that you like: in a .cpp file, a .h file, or create a dummy .cpp file if you like.

**See also**

- http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html
- http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmddef

Comment: Thanks for this - works nicely for me in the header file, allowing me to keep the documentation with the code.